# Invalid syntax error when in run mode, but when run with debug mode it runs normally

Tags: python, debugging, syntax

I am new to coding and I just started last month.
I checked for the problems but I couldn't find any, then I decided to run it with debugging and it worked

Here is my code:

```
class PB_stock:

    def __init__ (self, flavor, amount, old):
        self.flavor = flavor
        self.amount = int(amount)
        self.total = int(amount) + int(old)


choco_stock = PB_stock('choco', 500000, 10) 

print(choco_stock.total)
```

I tried to deconstruct the code to find the problem but with this, it still doesn't work.

Comment: It would be great if you included the error message, otherwise I don't know what is going wrong

Answer (score 0):

It looks like indentation error to me since your `def __init__` is declared inside the `class PB_stock:` indent it with 4 spaces like this.

```
class PB_stock:

    def __init__ (self, flavor, amount, old):
        self.flavor = flavor
        self.amount = int(amount)
        self.total = int(amount) + int(old)
```

This should work fine.